# Java Spring: Using correct file path?

Tags: java, spring, filepath

I am currently developing an application using Spring and I am using a local file path for a txt file , however this doesn't work when I upload my web app (obviously)

How can I use the correct file path so that my text file can be found with the web app?

Current code:

```
Scanner myScanner= new Scanner(new FileInputStream("C:/path/to/file");
```

How do I find what to replace `"C:/path/to/folder"` with so that the web app can be deployed.

Comment: Try to read from resource file path and put your file into src/main/resources

Comment: can you give me an example of this please? thanks

Comment: Shouldn't file system paths use \ not /?

Comment: I don't want to use the path on my local machine...that is the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171122/resource-from-src-main-resources-not-found-after-building-with-maven